# fuse changes chown to?

Tags: c, filesystems, fuse

i m trying to modify fuse [example](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html) to mount any directory. I want to mount /home/nikhil in tmp. 
i ran it as, 
`$ ./ni /home/nikhil tmp`

It mounts tmp folder, but cannot access it.

```
$ls -ltr tmp
```

`ls: cannot access tmp: Operation not permitted`

`$ ls -ltr`

`ls: cannot access delete: Operation not permitted
total 11716
d????????? ? ?      ?            ?                ? delete`

My code is

```
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include <fuse.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX 100
char *rootpath;

static void ni_fullpath(char fpath[MAX], const char *path){
    strcpy(fpath, rootpath);
    strncat(fpath, path, MAX);
}

static int ni_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
int res = 0;
char fpath[MAX];
memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    ni_fullpath(fpath, path);
res = lstat(fpath, stbuf);
return res;
}

static int ni_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
         off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
(void) offset;
(void) fi;
// i didnt understand this
filler(buf, ".", NULL, 0);
filler(buf, "..", NULL, 0);
    ni_fullpath(fpath, path);
filler(buf, fpath + 1, NULL, 0);

return 0;
}

static int ni_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
int fd;
char fpath[MAX];
ni_fullpath(fpath, path);
if ((fi->flags & 3) != O_RDONLY)
    return -EACCES;

fd = open(fpath, fi->flags);
return fd;
}

static int ni_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
          struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
return pread(fi->fh, buf, size, offset);

}

static struct fuse_operations ni_oper = {
.getattr    = ni_getattr,
.readdir    = ni_readdir,
.open       = ni_open,
.read       = ni_read,    
};


void ni_usage(){
fprintf(stderr, "usage ni rootDir mountPoint");
abort();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("%s %s \n", argv[1], argv[2]);
rootpath = realpath(argv[1], NULL);

argv[1] = argv[2];
argc--;
return fuse_main(argc, argv, &ni_oper, NULL);
}
```

Can anybody help what i m doing wrong ?
I m using ubuntu 1104 64 bit.

Comment: some one knowing python api for fuse can check the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using uninitialized var **fpath** instead of **path**?

```
static int ni_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
   int res = 0;
   char fpath[MAX];
   memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));

   res = lstat(fpath, stbuf);
   return res;
}
```

You probably missed **ni_fullpath(fpath, path);**

And as far as I understand the 0 should be returned in open callback if success, so it should look like:

```
   ....
   fd = open(fpath, fi->flags);
   if (fd < 0)
       return -errno;
   fi->fh = fd;
   return 0;
}
```

List operation should uses readdir callback, and in your case it has very limited application. It'd be better to start code on the basis of [fusexmp](http://www.gtoal.com/fusestuff/fuse-2.7.0/example/fusexmp.c.html). Check how readdir is implemented there.

Comment: thnks pmod for pointing it out. That is very silly mistake. i'm ashamed of it. I had missed another line in **ni_readdir**, `ni_fullpath(fpath, path); filler(buf, fpath + 1, NULL, 0);` Now code is working and dir tmp is mounted. But `ls -lt tmp` shows `ls -lt tmp ls: cannot access tmp /home/nikhil/: Operation not permitted total 0 ?????????? ? ? ? ? ? home/nikhil/`

Comment: this is interesting, i gave `/` to mount in `tmp`. It succeed. But if i give `/home/nikhil` to mount in `tmp` it is giving same error `operation not permitted`

Comment: I made change. Still problem persist. Only `/` is mounted. For other location it says `Operation not permitted.`

Comment: Check my update above. Now I suspect readdir and really advice start with fusexmp. Note, that you shouldn't use ni_fullpath() there.